# Android draw line and then drag it with touch

Tags: android, canvas, draw, drag

I am building an Android app that features the line drawing on canvas, which is showing over camera view. The purpose of it is to draw lines which provides an outlines for capturing image in that boundaries.
[image]

I am able to draw lines like this that are used as boundaries to take picture within it. But what i want is that i am not able to drag the line that i draw or if i want to scale the line after drawing. As currently have to be very careful when drawing the lines, and slight deviation requires do it again.

So can someone help me how i can implement drag listener on line, how to create line as object that can listen when finger is touched on a line?

Thanks, 
Irfan

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


            downx = event.getX();
            downy = event.getY();        

            fstTouch = downx;
            fstTouchx = downx;
            fstTouchY = downy;       
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upx = event.getX();
            upy = event.getY();

            if (actionE == 1) {
                actionE = 2;

                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, Manage_Template.mPaint);
                invalidate();
                editor.putFloat("downx", fstTouchx);
                editor.putFloat("downy", fstTouchY);
                editor.putString("fst", "2");
                editor.putFloat("newDownx", upx);
                editor.putFloat("newDowny", upy);
                editor.commit();

            } 
              else {

                fDownx = sharedPreferences.getFloat("downx", 0);
                fDowny = sharedPreferences.getFloat("downy", 0);
                newDownx = sharedPreferences.getFloat("newDownx", 0);
                newDowny = sharedPreferences.getFloat("newDowny", 0);


                fstLate = fstTouch - fDownx; //85-100=15
                scndLate = fstTouch - newDownx;//120-100=30

                st = String.valueOf(fstLate);
                sl = String.valueOf(scndLate);
                st = st.replace("-", "");
                sl = sl.replace("-", "");
                fstLate = Float.parseFloat(st);
                scndLate = Float.parseFloat(sl);

                if (fstLate >= scndLate) {

                    canvas.drawLine(newDownx, newDowny, upx, upy, Manage_Template.mPaint);
                    editor.putFloat("newDownx", upx);
                    editor.putFloat("newDowny", upy);
                    editor.commit();
                    invalidate();
                    Log.d("Action UP","fstlate>");

                } else {
                    canvas.drawLine(fDownx, fDowny, upx, upy, Manage_Template.mPaint);
                    editor.putFloat("downx", upx);
                    editor.putFloat("downy", upy);
                    editor.putFloat("newDownx", newDownx);
                    editor.putFloat("newDowny", newDowny);
                    editor.commit();
                    invalidate();
                    Log.d("Action UP","scndlate");
                }
            }
            // }

            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Add your test code

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an onTouchListener to do this. Here's an example I used when I was learning about it: [Using OnTouchListener](http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/)

I think the main thing you want, is to update the line during every `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and then leave the line where it is when you get a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do touch listener identify that user has clicked the line, as once a line is drawn on canvas, it is a fixed thing on it.
How do I then know the line is clicked, and then how to clear the already line and move it to other location?

Comment: I would say check this link out:  It helps you find the distance between the click and a line. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line  Then, for moving it, you'll have to clear the screen and redraw everything, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and solved it by using the concept of **Distance from point to line (geometry)**.
All you need to just apply this formula **shortestDistance= (event.x-drawingMarginLeft)**. Update the value of drawingMarginLeft in Action_Move. In my problem, I just move the line horizontal axis.